# Ansible - looping over result + when statement

Tags: ansible

My goal is to loop over interfces on cisco switch, check access vlan, and then change that vlan when is set to "12" or live as it is when is other then 12. To do that I save result to "int_out":

```
   - name: check vlan on some interfaces and save to int_out
     ios_command:
      commands: show run int Fa0/{{ item }} | incl switchport access vlan
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
     with_sequence: start=1 end=3 stride=1
     register: int_out
```

I would like to loop over the "int_out" result and use "when" statemant like below to change access vlan:

```
   - name: change vlan if needed
     ios_config:
      lines: switchport access vlan 1234
      parents: interface Fa0/{{item}}
     when: item.stdout_lines == " switchport access vlan 12"
     with_items: "{{ int_out.results }}"
```

but the comparison doesnt work:

```
TASK [change vlan when needed] *************************************************
skipping: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'1', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/1 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]}) 
skipping: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'2', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/2 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]}) 
skipping: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'3', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/3 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]})
```

If I check the output of "item.stdout_lines" to see waht's wrong:

```
   - debug: msg= "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
     with_items: "{{ int_out.results }}"
```

I get not only stdout_lines but a lot more:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'1', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/1 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "auth_pass": null, 
                "authorize": false, 
                "commands": [
                    "show run int Fa0/1 | incl switchport access vlan"
                ], 
                "host": "192.168.0.33", 
                "interval": 1, 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "port": 22, 
                "provider": "{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", 
                "retries": 10, 
                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                "timeout": 10, 
                "username": "admin", 
                "waitfor": null
            }, 
            "module_name": "ios_command"
        }, 
        "item": "1", 
        "stdout": [
            " switchport access vlan 12"
        ], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                " switchport access vlan 12"
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'2', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/2 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "auth_pass": null, 
                "authorize": false, 
                "commands": [
                    "show run int Fa0/2 | incl switchport access vlan"
                ], 
                "host": "192.168.0.33", 
                "interval": 1, 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "port": 22, 
                "provider": "{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", 
                "retries": 10, 
                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                "timeout": 10, 
                "username": "admin", 
                "waitfor": null
            }, 
            "module_name": "ios_command"
        }, 
        "item": "2", 
        "stdout": [
            " switchport access vlan 12"
        ], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                " switchport access vlan 12"
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [192.168.0.33] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': [u' switchport access vlan 12'], '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'3', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ios_command', u'module_args': {u'authorize': False, u'username': u'admin', u'commands': [u'show run int Fa0/3 | incl switchport access vlan'], u'auth_pass': None, u'retries': 10, u'waitfor': None, u'interval': 1, u'host': u'192.168.0.33', u'ssh_keyfile': None, u'timeout': 10, u'provider': u"{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", u'password': u'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', u'port': 22}}, u'stdout_lines': [[u' switchport access vlan 12']]}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "auth_pass": null, 
                "authorize": false, 
                "commands": [
                    "show run int Fa0/3 | incl switchport access vlan"
                ], 
                "host": "192.168.0.33", 
                "interval": 1, 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "port": 22, 
                "provider": "{'username': 'admin', 'host': '192.168.0.33', 'password': '********'}", 
                "retries": 10, 
                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                "timeout": 10, 
                "username": "admin", 
                "waitfor": null
            }, 
            "module_name": "ios_command"
        }, 
        "item": "3", 
        "stdout": [
            " switchport access vlan 12"
        ], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                " switchport access vlan 12"
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": ""
}
```

But when I run code like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{int_out.results[1].stdout}}"
```

I get such response:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.33] => {
    "msg": [
        " switchport access vlan 12"
    ]
}
```

Any idea whats wron'g and how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you take close look at `int_out.results` elements, you'll notice that `stdout` is a list of strings, and `stdout_lines` is a list of lists.
I suspect `ios_config` module returns a list as `stdout` (instead of multiline string in `command`/`shell` modules) and Ansible's standard result processor splits any `stdout` variable into a new list.

So you just need to tweak your `when:` statement as follows:

```
when: item.stdout[0] == " switchport access vlan 12"
```

to access first element of `stdout` list.

Comment: Great. This is it!

Comment: Thank you for your help.